# Linux Mint fails to install grub-efi-amd64 package

Tags: linux-mint, grub

I've recently decided to replace Windows with Linux Mint 18. I made a bootable USB to install it, I've turned secure boot off. Whenever I try to install it, no matter if I partition things manually or do an automatic install, it always gives me this "grub-efi-amd64​ package failed to install to /target/". I'm running out of ideas on what to do.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you boot the *Live CD* in UEFI mode by looking for the entry that looks like *[UEFI] USB Flash Drive* or something similar. Then you can partition everything yourself, but make sure you make one partition formatted as *ext4* which has **at the very least** 700MB of size and mark it as */boot*-partition. Then create a partition of size ~400MB, format it as *FAT32* and mark it as *EFI*-partition.
 And of course you have to make sure the *root*-partition has enough space anyway.

Also you should make sure to change the *partition table* to *GPT*.

But beware of one thing: the first step is **crucial**. If your machine does not support EFI, then it won't work. You have to make sure to choose the entry saying something like:
*[UEFI] USB Flash Drive*.

Comment: Okay so this time the installation worked, but there's no bootloader. When I start up, it takes me to my computer's BIOS settings. How do I get it to boot into grub?

Comment: Are you sure you did everything the *EFI* way? If yes, then just download *rescatux* or *boot-repair* Live CD, boot up into that and follow the easy instructions. Just choose *Recommended repair* and everything should be fine.

Comment: I got it solved. I had to turn off fast boot, not only secure boot!

Comment: That's weird. I never had an issue with that, regarding Linux boot ups.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I installed Mint 18.3 from LiveCD alongside with Windows 10.
The installation failed when it tried to put grub on /dev/sda (in my case).
I put attention that:

- When installation is running from LiveCD then no drives (/dev/sda, /dev/sdb etc) available. I believe that's the main reason for grub installation failure.
- When I run GParted from LiveCD I see the same effect: /dev/sda, /dev/sdb etc become unavailable. However, when I exit GParted, *the devices become available again*.

So, my steps were:

1. Run Mint installation from within LiveCD session *=> disk devices become unavailable*.
2. While the installation is running, run GParted and wait while GParted accesses disk devices list *=> disk devices are still unavailable*.
3. Quit Gparted => ***disk devices become available!***
4. By the end of Mint installation it tries to install grub on /dev/sda and... voilà! Installation completed successfully!